# Java, ICEFaces and folder browse / select dialog

Tags: java, icefaces

I'm currently developing an ICEFaces web application and I need a folder browsing / selection control. Anyone found a solution to this?

Additional info: The application generates files that has to be stored on the local machine, so the user has to choose where this should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
<ice:inputFile/>
```

component. Through this you will be able to do the file uploads flawlessly.

```
<ice:inputFile id="inputFile1" actionListener="#{bean.ipfActionListener}"
 fileNamePattern=".+\.xls" uniqueFolder="true" uploadDirectory="<Your Location>"/>
```

The above fragement will filter files with .xls extension while displaying the filechooser dialog.

Comment: Folder browsing / selection with inputFile, how?

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example. The said component is just like a java FileDialog. It will open a dialog with the directories in your computer (or the client's computer) from where files can be selected and uploaded.

Comment: Did you bother to read my question? I need a folder selection dialog which is native to the OS, not a filedialog.

Comment: And where you need this dialog to be placed.. Let be guess.. on a web page. Isn't it? Well having an FTP server will make things easier..

Comment: Additionally there is an "uniqueFolder" attribute where you can place the files.

Comment: As far as I can read the documentation the uniqueFolder attribute is unrelated. To give an example of what I need look at this .NET / navtive windows dialog: http://www.functionx.com/dlgboxes/browse3.gif

Answer (score 0):

ICEfaces does not have access to
the file system on the web browser computer for security reasons.
So there is no ICEfaces component for choosing a directory to
download a file into.  Other JavaScript libraries have the same limitation.

Normally, when a non-displayable file such as a ZIP file is download the web
browser prompts you to save the file.  My Firefox web browser
has the option '*Always ask me where to save files*' and with
this option I get a native file selection dialog and
can control where each downloaded file is stored.  Can you use
this approach instead?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the webapp im developing compares dirs on the client computer and instead of providing two ice:inputText components with validation, I wanted to let the user select the directories directly. I guess the underlying problem is what you suggest - that the limitation is a security issue, although I am unable to see the distinction between a file browsing dialog vs the folder browsing dialog when it comes to security. Both dialogs access the local filesystem. ICEFaces along with other web libraries merely expose basic html and do not provide native os supported ui components.